# Calculation of prob. distribution

Tags: calculus, probability

[image]

Is this formula true?

If not, what conditions do you need in order for this formula to be true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For suitable meanings of $p$, you may find it easier to justify
$$p(w\mid \theta, \beta)= \sum_z p(w\mid z, \theta, \beta)\,p(z\mid \theta, \beta)$$

so you might want $p(w\mid z, \theta, \beta)= p(w\mid z,  \beta)$ and $p(z\mid \theta, \beta)=p(z\mid \theta)$ for all $z, \theta, \beta$ to get your original expression.

---

As a counter-example to your original expression, suppose the following combinations are equally likely

```
w   θ   β   z

0   0   0   0
0   0   0   1
0   1   0   0
1   1   0   1
0   0   1   1
1   0   1   0
1   1   1   0
1   1   1   1
```

Then $\mathbb{P}(w=0\mid \theta=0, \beta=0)= \frac{2}{2}=1$

But $\mathbb{P}(w=0\mid z=0, \beta=0)\,\mathbb{P}(z=0\mid \theta=0)+\mathbb{P}(w=0\mid z=1, \beta=0)\,\mathbb{P}(z=1\mid \theta=0) $ $ =\frac{2}{2}\times\frac{2}{4}+\frac{1}{2}\times\frac{2}{4}=\frac34$ which is different